# Java Heap memory usage fluctuation

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Hello dear fellow developers,

I am facing issue with heap memory usage in my java application.
Application itself is simply accepts Socket connections

Main Thread I have following script nothing more (except static ExecutorService instance):

```
ServerSocketFactory serverFactory = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
ServerSocket server = serverFactory.createServerSocket(Configuration.port);
for(;;)
{
  Socket client = server.accept();
  Configuration.getExecutor().submit(new Client(client));
}
```

When Application is running, it should block loop until someone gets connected...
Which means my Main thread is on waiting state most of the time...

**The problem is: When no one is connected to my Server, Heap memory usage is fluctuating (see screenshot below)** 
Which means there is a memory leak? no? Or it is the natural way how java application behaves?

[image: JConsole]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If there were a memory leak, the usage would be **increasing**.

Comment: Just looks like normal GC activity to me. You can adjust the aggressiveness of the GC strategy using various JVM args, but this looks normal. I would just move along.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Kayaman :)

Comment: Will it affect to performance? if I will make maximum possible aggressiveness :) @MarkW

Comment: Yes, there is one setting in particular that effects what % of CPU time is spent in GC. The default settings allow the heap to grow until it approaches the maximum, then GC will run (I think). More aggressive options will spend more time in GC and consequently less time on user code. You should only modify the GC strategy if you have a specific reason to. Again, the output of your profiler there seems pretty typical. I wouldn't consider any of that problematic.

Comment: I thought I would also add that the JVM allocates memory for the heap at startup. The initial value and the max value can be set with some JVM args, but ultimately, that memory is reserved for the JVM regardless if the app is actually using it. If your initial heap size is 100MB and you only use 20, windows still reserves 100MB for the JVM. The max heap size can grow as the program needs more, up to the maximum. Those args are -Xmx and -Xms for Max and initial respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `visualvm` or `jconsole` or `jmc` to monitor heap usage it uses RMI and JMX which creates quite a lot of garbage. i.e. it is your monitoring which is doing this.

BTW even if you have a simple program

```
System.in.read();
```

these tools will show that garbage is being created, but not by your program.

I suggest you try instead use

```
jps -lvm
```

to get the process id or `pid`

```
jstat -gccause {pid} 10s
```

to monitor the memory usage.  This also creates a small amount of garbage much far less.

Comment: Peter, Don't you recommend using JMX/RMI based monitoring application in that case?

Answer (score 3):

Your memory usage is fluctuating between 0 and 20MB and not increasing. There is neither a memory leak or any reason why you should pay any attention to this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something is getting garbage collected. Remember that on a computer with realistic amounts of main memory, that slope will appear a thousand times smaller. I don't think it's worth worrying about.